# BIND9 start-up problem!

Tags: 14.04, dns

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu Server and I'm having trouble using BIND9 on Ubuntu Server 14.05.5.
My problem is BIND9 doesn't seem to start up correctly when I do a full reboot of my server. After a manual service restart BIND9 started running again. I'm wondering if there's a work-around to this?
Thanks so much in advance guys!

Comment: By enabling service it automatically start on system boot

Comment: Hi Kartik Agarwa, I had it fixed by change the boot up order of BIND9 and my DHCP service. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform this command:
**sudo update-rc.d "name of your service" defaults**

It will add your service in autostart.

Comment: The start/stop links for bind9 already exist on my system, when I do a reboot on my server, the bind9 service did start but I can't resolve DNS until after a service restart. weird...

Comment: Ok, first I misunderstood you.
Could you show the BIND log after the start system?

Comment: Apr 14 17:22:13 CTL named[1319]: zone 128.81.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 4
Apr 14 17:22:13 CTL named[1319]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Apr 14 17:22:13 CTL named[1319]: zone loc/IN: loaded serial 3
Apr 14 17:22:13 CTL named[1319]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Apr 14 17:22:13 CTL named[1319]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Apr 14 17:22:13 CTL named[1319]: all zones loaded
Apr 14 17:22:13 CTL named[1319]: running
Apr 14 17:22:13 CTL named[1319]: zone loc/IN: sending notifies (serial 3)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In the log after the system started, it indicates that my DNS zone is loaded in serial 4 and everything is fine although I can't resolve the DNS in that zone from a client.

Comment: Ah sorry guys, I figure out the problem. My DHCP service boot up order is after the BIND9 so it wasn't able to bind the interface for listening. I change the order then it works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help, I had to check the log file to figure that out

Comment: I'm glad that you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the bind9 service with the command.

`sudo systemctl enable bind9`

Comment: Ah sorry guys, I figure out the problem. My DHCP service boot up order is after the BIND9 so it wasn't able to bind the interface for listening. I change the order then it works like a charm